# camera matrix original image

Tags: android, matrix, camera, root

As I know, when you using camera it crops some part of image. I mean that the application cuts out that part of the photo that goes beyond the rectangle.
Is there any way to get the original image that is full-sized and received directly from the camera's matrix?
Root access on my device is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small demo years ago:

https://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/demos/camera-utils/src/main/java/net/sf/javaocr/demos/android/utils/camera/CameraManager.java#l8

Basic idea  is to set up callback,   then you raw image data is delivered  via byte array ( getPreviewFrame() / onPreviewFrame ) - no root access is necessary.

Actually, this data comes as mmapped memory buffer directly from adress space  of camera app - no root is necessary

As this byte array does not provide any meta information,  you  have to get all the params from camera object yourself